# find all $k$ that $k^{18}+k^9+1$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $\displaystyle k \in \{1,2,...,200 \}$. Find all $k$ that $k^{18}+k^9+1$ is prime.

I don't know how I should start to solve.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: No obvious congruences here. I'll throw in [the factordb query](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=x%5E18%2Bx%5E9%2B1&use=x&x=1&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PR=on&PRP=on&CF=on&U=on&C=on&perpage=20&format=1&sent=Show).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584594/find-all-n-for-which-n8-n-1-is-prime?rq=1

Comment: @AsharTafhim I saw it but I think this problem can not be factorized as $n^8+n+1$ problem.

Comment: we can find a factor of the polynomial by an appropriate 27-root.

Comment: How to find it? I'm confused.

Comment: well, we know that $k^{27}=1 mod p$ since k is a 27-root mod p

Comment: Can you show it? I can't do.

Comment: @AsharTafhim Except the polynomial given is an irreducible polynomial, and so that approach reduces the problem to itself.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I'm so confused. How should I solve it?

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs No clue. Problems like this usually have very ad hoc solutions, and no fun tricks are coming to mind for me.

Comment: Thank you, This is my problem that my professor gave. I can't solve it by myself.

Comment: For what class did the professor give you this exercise? Was it by any chance computational number theory?

Comment: For simplifying by hand, consider $k$ such that $k^{27}=1$ (mod 109), or $k^{27}=1$ (mod 163).and $k \neq 1$ modulo those primes. You can solve these congruences and then eliminate all such $k$. In addition, sieve out values modulo small primes, eg: eliminate $k$ which are 1 modulo 3.

Comment: Indeed, just eliminate the following values of $k$: $a^4$ (mod 109) and $b^6$ (mod 163), $a,b>1$.

Comment: I'm so confused, Can you explain more? @Aravind

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(k)=k^{18}+k^9+1$. Here are all values of $k\in[1,200]$ for which $f(k)$ is prime:
$$k=1, \quad f(k)=3;$$
$$k=2, \quad f(k)=262657;$$
$$k=11, \quad f(k)=5559917315850179173;$$
$$k=44, \quad f(k)=382074608478613638297145835521;$$
$$k=45, \quad f(k)=572565594852444913327371093751;$$
$$k=56, \quad f(k)=29334891491018192696865258995713;$$
$$k=62, \quad f(k)=183252712161029676119898789920257;$$
$$k=63, \quad f(k)=244416145091043028178779946569153;$$
$$k=110, \quad f(k)=5559917313492231483357947691000000001;$$
$$k=170, \quad f(k)=14063084452067724991127587876497000000001.
$$

Solved using this one-line program in PARI/GP:

```
for (k=1,200,n=k^18+k^9+1;if(isprime(n),print(k," ",n)))
```

Comment: Can It be solved without program? I don't know how program solve it.

Comment: Judging by other comments, a programmatic solution seems the easiest.

Comment: It is allways a good idea to check [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A153440)